# How to apply css only to React child component

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a child component needs to use spectre.css, but when I import spectre.css in child component, parent component also got affected. How can I make spectre.css only apply to the child component? Thanks

Parent Component:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return <ChildComponent></ChildComponent>
    }
}
```

In Child component,

```
import from 'spectre.css'

class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: it is about the way you write your css. You may need to follow BEM to isolate your css for components from the others or you can take a look css-in-js

Answer (score 0):

most probably your css is bundled in one single file.

- You can add `className` to your components, to differentiate them.
- you can create your styles inside your component

```
const styles= {
  wrapper: {
    color: red,
  },
};

class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
    /* ... */
   render() {
      return (<div style={styles.wrapper}> </div>
   }
}
```

- or you can try **css-in-js** libraries such as [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) or [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/)